# Computing mod with fractions

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know that $12(7)^{-(1)}=31(mod 41)$, but I have no idea why.  $12(7)^{-(1)}=12/7 \approx 1.714285714$. This is an isolated part of an example of the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm that I'm trying to understand.

Comment: $$7^{-1} \pmod{41} = 6 \implies 12 \times 7^{-1} \pmod{41} = 12 \times 6 \pmod{41} = 31 \pmod{41}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General rule:  NEVER think about fractions when working modularly.

$7^{-1}$ does NOT mean anything resembling $\frac{1}{7}$.  Instead, $7^{-1}$ means an integer $k$ such that
$$
7k = 1 \bmod 41.
$$
Such a solution is unique (when it exists) when chosen to be $1 \leq k \leq 40$.  These inverses might not exist, but since 41 is a prime, they always do (except for $0$).

In your case, note that $7 \cdot 6 = 42 =1 \bmod 41$, so $7^{-1}=6$.

Comment: Just to add on, the proper term is "modular multiplicative inverse". You also didn't say *when* it exists (apart from asserting that it always exists when the modulus is prime). The necessary and sufficient condition for $a$ to have an inverse modulo $b$ (or, in other words, $ax \equiv 1 \pmod b$ has a solution $x \pmod b$ is when $\mathrm {gcd}(a,b) = 1$, i.e. $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: Well I wasn't going to give a whole course in ring theory...

Comment: Of course not, but it's important to be precise. For example, no solution exists for $82k \equiv 1 \pmod{41}$. So your assertion that a solution always exists for any value other than $0$ is untrue. Of course, $82 \equiv 0 \pmod {41}$, so in a sense $82$ is "equivalent" to zero, but that's something that may not be realised by a novice to modular math (which I believe the OP to be). I did upvote your answer because I think it's good. I just wanted to add a little more detail in comments.

Comment: That is indeed a good point (for the OP's benefit, the point of the question/answer process).